# YouTube Music playlist is broken while listening in AirPods 2

Tags: iphone, ios, airpods

**What do I have**: iPhone with iOS 15.1, AirPods 2 (4C165), YouTube Music 4.55.3.

I experience an **issue** with YouTube Music and AirPods. For some reason playlist stops on random songs and never goes forward, even I manually tap the AirPod to go one track forward. Manual tap on AirPod just replays the song playlist is stuck at. So I had to unlock the iPhone, open YouTube Music app and manually select next track.

The whole playlist is downloaded on the device.

**What have I tried** (without success): updating the YouTube Music app, reconnecting AirPods to the iPhone.

Comment: Have you tried other headphones or without headphones?

Comment: @JBallin thanks, I'll try without headphones.